# How to use Scanner to get an object input from user through command line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String line1 = input.nextLine();
```

i understand that this is how you would get a string line from command line, but what would you do if you want to get an object class from the command line?

Comment: Scanner plus reflection. See here to learn about reflection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: The first question is: Why do you need an object through the command line?

You'll allways can receive a bunch of data and parsing it in order to create an object using a factory, but I think that is easyer storing objects that extends serializable and giving your program a path to recover it.

Comment: How do you expect a user to enter a full object?

Comment: Could you specify why do you need to pass an object? Or maybe you just want the user to give it a name to that object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment but...

Why would someone enter an object in the command line? I mean, I don't even know if that's possible.

The only thing I know possible is the dynamic creation of objects in java:

```
Console> myproject.main.Person
```

And then read the inserted line and:

```
Person p = (Person) Class.forName(line1).newInstance();
```

This will attempt to create an instance of the class Person in the myproject/main package.

Or you can simply ask a load of data through console (eg. bithdate,name,height) and then create a new instance of the object, passing that data through constructor.

Comment: Thanks guys, i have solved this issue already by taking in a string